# How to get speciffic element to <dl> using querySelector in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I'm begginer user from puppeteer, but cannot search this selector on code,
can someone tell me how can I get the CSS selector of element which holds dl content  in above HTML?

i'm trying to use selectorall and selector but only return undefined

Code to trying get elements

```
await page.waitFor(".row > div:nth-child(2) > div");
  let list = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const getInnerTextForSelector = selector => {
      const element = document.querySelector(selector);
      if (element) return element.innerText;
      return "Selector not found";
    };

    return {
      title: getInnerTextForSelector('h5[class="card-title"]'),
      subtitle: getInnerTextForSelector(
        'h6[class="card-subtitle mb-2 text-muted"]'
      ),
      sit: getInnerTextForSelector("div > dt:nth-child(1)"),
    };
  });
```

Class to get.

```
<div class="col-lg">
<dl class="row">
<dt class="col-sm-3">Situação</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">Entrada</dd>
<dt class="col-sm-3">Trâmite</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">10/02/2020</dd>
<dt class="col-sm-3">Regime</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">Ordinário</dd>
<dt class="col-sm-3">Assunto</dt><dd class="col-sm-9">Diversos</dd>
<dt class="col-sm-3">Autor</dt>
<dd class="col-sm-9">Vereador<br>
<b>CLEITON MARCIO FOSSÁ</b>.
</dd>
</dl>
</div>
```

Comment: Which result do you expect?

Comment: I need get return { Situação, Assunto, Autor} respective lines.

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you can't unless you had some form of unique attribute such as id or data that can allow them to be distinguishable within the XML document.

If you want you could use a custom attribute like

```
<dt class="col-sm-3" data-ref="Regime">Regime</dt>
```

and select it like so

```
[data-ref="Regime"]
```

You could also use querySelectorAll("dt") and then use JS to iterate through the values to find the one one you want?

ps: little more on [Selector Attributes](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/a/attribute/), I know it says CSS but they work the same and gives a good visual sense of whats happening :)

Comment: i'm try to use in puppeteer, but only return null.

Comment: Are you using any frameworks such as React, Angular, vue or just vanilla HTML?

Comment: True, it will return null if it is unable to find the element, have you tried this at all to just check that your selector path hasn't changed at all for the element you are trying to select? 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GMk7ZLuo6Po